# Regex in Netscape Navigator 9

Tags: regex, netscape

I have a regex pattern for a telephone number field which allows the user to enter either 10 numbers or 0. I have tested it and confirmed it is working in Google Chrome, Internet Explorer, Firefox, Opera and safari but for some reason it is not working in Netscape Navigator 9. Any help is very much appreciated.

Thank you

```
pattern="^[0-9]{10}$|^[0-9]{0}$"
```

Comment: What you get then? Any error?

Comment: This is just not supported in Firefox 2, which is the base for Netscape Navigator 9. See: https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern

Comment: @revo I do not get an error just goes through with any amount of characters

Comment: @qqilihq Is there another way of doing this if regex is not supported?

Comment: If you really really really need/want/must support a ten year old browser: You could do the validation with JS.

Comment: @qqilihq do you know of a good browser detection scripts that don't send back Netscape for firefox and ie? I am having trouble finding one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new trend is to not detect specific browsers, but rather support for the feature you need; in this case "pattern".

```
var el = document.createElement('input');
var isPatternSupported = (el.pattern === undefined);

alert(isPatternSupported); // Displays `false` for NN9 and `true` for modern browsers
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!